# Scala Macro detecting javac classes

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Is there any way with a scala macro to detect which classes have been compiled using javac? I would like to effectively mark javac compiled classes as "unsafe" or "impure".

Thanks.

Comment: You could check the Source File attribute. If it ends with `.java`, it's compiled from Java code. I don't know if the Scala compiler retains this attribute in its AST, and you can't rely on it to be always present.